# Postgres не запускается при старте системы

Tags: postgresql

При старте системы postgres не работает.
Когда пишешь `service postgres status`:

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled;
>   vendor preset: enabled)
>       Active: active (exited) since Сб 2017-08-19 12:41:17 MSK; 6h ago

После того как сервис перезагрузишь, то всё работает хорошо. Без перезагрузки при запуске psql пишет:

> psql: could not connect to server: Нет такого файла или каталога
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

В логах вот это:

> 2017-08-19 12:41:17 MSK [1253-1] LOG:  could not translate host name
>   "localhost", service "5432" to address: Временный сбой в разрешении
>   имен
>       2017-08-19 12:41:17 MSK [1253-2] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
>       2017-08-19 12:41:17 MSK [1253-3] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets

Система ubuntu

Comment: Если не сложно приложите пожалуйста еще содержимое вашего файла /etc/hosts